# Are lateral views available in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to do something like this using BigQuery. 
Input Table

```
|Col1  | Col2 |
|------|------|
|1     | A,B,C|
```

Output Table

```
|Col1  | Col2 |
|------|------|
|1     |  A   |
|1     |  B   |
|1     |  C   |
```

Is there some way of doing above operation in `BigQuery`. The same functionality can be achieved in Hive using Lateral Views .

Comment: was there some formatting lost while asking the question? the example lines look very flat

Comment: I have reformatted ... Please help

Comment: So the first table has two columns, and you want to split a comma separated value into 3 rows?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I want.. Split comma separated value into rows. Please help me on the same.

Comment: good news, BigQuery now supports SPLIT()

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should work:

```
select
  col1,
  split(col2) as col2_split
from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no split() function in BigQuery, that would be useful in this case to split by commas. But you can use regular expressions to get the same result, with REGEXP_REPLACE.

Check the answer to this question:

[find all two word phrases that appear in more than one row in a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709547/find-all-two-word-phrases-that-appear-in-more-than-one-row-in-a-dataset/18711812#18711812)