# How to find n-grams with the reddit dataset with BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, reddit

I'm looking at the reddit dataset, and an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172994/how-to-find-the-most-common-bi-grams-with-bigquery) that looks into finding bi-grams with BigQuery - however the answer to that question doesn't work well with URLs, quotes, etc. Is there a better way to do it and also generalize it to tri-grams instead of bi-grams?

Answer (score 5):

This will do:

```
SELECT word, nextword, nextword2, COUNT(*) c 
FROM (
SELECT pos, id, word, LEAD(word) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY pos) nextword, LEAD(word, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY pos) nextword2 FROM (
SELECT id, word, pos FROM FLATTEN(
  (SELECT id, REGEXP_REPLACE(word, 'QUOTE', "'") word, POSITION(word) pos FROM
   (SELECT id, SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(body), "'", 'QUOTE'), r'http.?://[^ ]*', r'URL'), r'\b', ' '), ' ') word 
    FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01]
    WHERE score>200
    HAVING REGEXP_MATCH(word, '[a-zA-Z0-9]')
   )
  ), word)
))
WHERE nextword IS NOT null
GROUP EACH BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 100
```

(note that I'm filtering to comments with a >200 score for faster results - you can do the full month moving that filter)