# parse each row of the table and display distinct values sql

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I am working on a public [dataset](https://empirical-software.engineering/projects/sotorrent/) where I need to parse each row of the Table Posts. So, for example, three rows under the column `tags` have values:

```
1. <c#><.net>
2. <android> <python> <sockets> <android-studio><socket.io>
3. <android-studio><socket.io><.net>
```

I need to display the output as:

```
1. c#
2. .net
3. android
4. python
5. sockets
6. android-studio
7. socket.io
```

Is there a way I could do it in BigQuery?

Comment: 1) mysql or bigquery? 2) what you tried so far? I downvoted because [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: the data set is uploaded on bigquery

Comment: @Mahad So this has nothing to do with MySQL?

Comment: i have no idea how to do this I'm a beginner and tried this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127540/return-top-100-words-from-strings

Comment: @Mahad This might get you closer to what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413901/splitting-a-string-column-in-bigquery

Comment: @Error_2646 I will try it and let you know if it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you familiar with unix commands set, awk, uniq?

Answer (score 1):

You can first use `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` to match all the words inside < >'s, and then `UNNEST` the resulting arrays to flatted the output:

```
select e from (
select regexp_extract_all(x, r'<([^>]*)>') e
from unnest([
"<c#><.net>",
"<android> <python> <sockets> <android-studio><socket.io>",
"<android-studio><socket.io><.net>"
]) x), unnest(e) e
```

Produces

```
Row e   
1       c#
2       .net
3       android
4       python
5       sockets
6       android-studio
7       socket.io
8       android-studio
9       socket.io
10      .net
```

And to eliminate duplicates - run `DISTINCT`:

```
select distinct e from (
select regexp_extract_all(x, r'<([^>]*)>') e
from unnest([
"<c#><.net>",
"<android> <python> <sockets> <android-studio><socket.io>",
"<android-studio><socket.io><.net>"
]) x), unnest(e) e
```

Comment: Thank you very much. for your support

Comment: i did it like this

Comment: SELECT  REGEXP_EXTRACT(Tags, r'<([^>]*)>') As T
 FROM [sotorrent-org:2018_09_23.Posts]
 GROUP BY T

Comment: Looks like you are using Legacy SQL, I recommend switching to Standard SQL (my solution uses it)

Comment: It looks like the answer solved the question. If that's true, it is a good idea to accept the answer, but if not please indicate what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT tag
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(tags, r'<([^>]*)>')) tag
```

You can test/play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '<c#><.net>' tags UNION ALL
  SELECT '<android> <python> <sockets> <android-studio><socket.io>' UNION ALL
  SELECT '<android-studio><socket.io><.net>'
)
SELECT DISTINCT tag
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(tags, r'<([^>]*)>')) tag
```

with result

```sql
Row tag  
1   c#   
2   .net     
3   android  
4   python   
5   sockets  
6   android-studio   
7   socket.io
```