# Bigquery sql query to extract Twitter usernames from tweets

Tags: sql, twitter, google-bigquery

I have a large table with tweets containing a username and tweet text per row. The tweet text has often mentionings (@username). I want to extract all usernames and build a new table for a social network analysis, where each row has one mentioning.

Example rows:

```
|-------------------|--------------------------------------|
|      username     |     tweet                            |
|-------------------|--------------------------------------|
|      userA        |     great stuff @userC and @userB    |
|-------------------|--------------------------------------|
|      userB        |     thanks for mentioning @userE     |
|-------------------|--------------------------------------|
```

Shall result in:

```
 |-------------------|--------------------------------------|
 |      tweet_by     |     repied_to                        |
 |-------------------|--------------------------------------|
 |      userA        |     userC                            |
 |-------------------|--------------------------------------|
 |      userA        |     userB                            |
 |-------------------|--------------------------------------|
 |      userB        |     userE                            |
 |-------------------|--------------------------------------|
```

I found this question, but I could not figure out a solution with split() and regexp_extract: [Transform data in Google bigquery - extract text, split it into multiple columns and pivoting the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282901/transform-data-in-google-bigquery-extract-text-split-it-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below simple option. it should work as your extraction criteria is quite simple I think. Unless you want to handle some edge cases

```
SELECT 
  username AS tweet_by, 
  SPLIT(tweet, ' ') AS repied_to 
FROM YourTable
HAVING LEFT(repied_to, 1) = '@'
```

> Added - to address potential use cases like

```
userA     great stuff @userC&@userB  
userB     thanks for mentioning  @userE!  
userC     great stuff  @userC,@userB
```

Query

```
SELECT
  tweet_by,
  REPLACE(word, '@', '') AS repied_to
FROM (  
  SELECT 
    username AS tweet_by,
    SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(tweet, r'([^\w@])', ' '), ' ') AS word 
  FROM YourTable
  HAVING LEFT(word, 1) = '@'
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that works great. Can you maybe give an example of such an edge case?

Comment: didn't mean anything in particular, but let's say if it is just arbitrary text as 'great stuff \@userC,\@userB ' - query in answer will just extract '\@userC,\@userB' - so in this/such cases you would need to put more logic into query in order to extract \@userC and \@userB separately - (btw- ignore \ in \@)