# BigQuery: SPLIT() returns only one value

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a page URL column components of which are delimited by `/`. I tried to run the `SPLIT()` function in BigQuery but it only gives the first value. I want all values in specific columns.

I don't understand how to use the `Regexp_extract()` example mentioned in [Split string into multiple columns with bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154275/split-string-into-multiple-columns-with-bigquery).

I need something similar to `REGEX_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(<String>, <DELIMITER>)` which converts a single string into multiple columns.

**Query:**

```
SELECT PK, 
DATE(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(SUBSTR(date,1,4),'-',SUBSTR(date,5,2),'-',SUBSTR(date,7,2),' 00:00:00'))) as visit_date,
hits_page_pagePath,
split(hits_page_pagePath,'/')
FROM [Intent.All2mon] limit 100
```

Comment: what does the data look like?

Comment: Hi Felipe, Can you please help me understand how to prepare regular expression to extract information from each entity within '/' symbols?

Comment: You can't generate a variable number of columns in BigQuery, only a constant number of columns, so you can't do exactly what you want.  If you can set an upper bound on the number of URL components, then you can generate that many columns and make them NULL when a particular URL has fewer components.

Answer (score 83):

### 2018 standardSQL update:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT SPLIT(path, '/')[OFFSET(0)] part1,
       SPLIT(path, '/')[OFFSET(1)] part2,
       SPLIT(path, '/')[OFFSET(2)] part3
FROM (SELECT "/a/b/aaaa?c" path)
```

---

Now I understand you want them in different columns.

An alternative to the query you provided:

```
SELECT FIRST(SPLIT(path, '/')) part1,
       NTH(2, SPLIT(path, '/')) part2,
       NTH(3, SPLIT(path, '/')) part3
FROM (SELECT "/a/b/aaaa?c" path)
```

`NTH(X, SPLIT(s))` will provide the Xth value from the SPLIT. `FIRST(s)` is the same as `NTH(1, s)`

Comment: can you provide a check if the [OFFSET(2)] doesn't exist in some cases so it won't overflow? Something like: `IF(SPLIT(path, '/')[OFFSET(2)].doesnt_exist), Null, SPLIT(path, '/')[OFFSET(2)]` ?

Comment: Prefix with SAFE. - or post a new question ;)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa, the second query doesn't seem to work in BigQuery. But the first one works cool!

Answer (score 11):

You can also try the following with SPLIT function, however you need to know how many '/' your url would have or make enough entries so that if your url contains more '/' then you can still get those values in the seperate columns

```
  SPLIT(`url`, '/')[safe_ordinal(1)] AS `Col1`, 
  SPLIT(`url`, '/')[safe_ordinal(2)] AS `Col2`,
  SPLIT(`url`, '/')[safe_ordinal(3)] AS `Col3`, 
  SPLIT(`url`, '/')[safe_ordinal(4)] AS `Col4`,
  .
  .
  SPLIT(`url`, '/')[safe_ordinal(N)] AS `ColN`
```

Answer (score 3):

in standard sql, you can use the following functions:

```
array[OFFSET(zero_based_offset)]
array[ORDINAL(one_based_ordinal)]
```

so

```
SELECT SPLIT(path, '/')[OFFSET(1)] part2,
       SPLIT(path, '/')[ORDINAL(2)] part2_again,
       SPLIT(path, '/')[ORDINAL(3)] part3
FROM (SELECT "/a/b/aaaa?c" path)

part2   part2_again part3    
a       a           b
```

`part1` in this case, is empty string (before the first slash)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT SPLIT(path, '/') part
FROM (SELECT "/a/b/aaaa?c" path)

Row part     
1   a    
2   b    
3   aaaa?c
```

Not sure why it wouldn't work for you. What does your data look like?

Comment: SPLIT() splits the column value into rows without adding a row_number against it.

Comment: What I need, is a way to segregate every instance of string between  '/' into separate columns...without running a separate split() query for each possible instance...

Comment: I have built this query: SELECT
date, hits_time, fullVisitorId, visitNumber, hits_hitNumber,
hits_page_pagePath,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(hits_page_pagePath,r'/(\w*)\/') as one,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(hits_page_pagePath,r'/\w*\/(\w*)') as two,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(hits_page_pagePath,r'/.*\/.*\/(.*)\/') as three
from
[Intent.All2mon] 
limit 1000     but it still doesnt separate out the strings...

Comment: that should have worked - can you share a sample dataset so I can run queries over your data? I don't have access to [Intent.All2mon]

Comment: NOTE: If you select a destination table and uncheck "flatten results", you will get a single row with a repeated parts column.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it in a way.

```
   SELECT
   date, 
   hits_time, 
   fullVisitorId, 
   visitNumber, 
   hits_hitNumber,
   X.page_path,
   REGEXP_EXTRACT(X.page_path,r'/(\w*)\/') as one,
   REGEXP_EXTRACT(X.page_path,r'/\w*\/(\w*)') as two,
   REGEXP_EXTRACT(X.page_path,r'/\w*\/\w*\/(\w*)') as three,
   REGEXP_EXTRACT(X.page_path,r'/\w*/\w*/\w*\/(\w*)\/.*') as four
   from
   (
   select 
   date, hits_time, fullVisitorId, visitNumber, hits_hitNumber,
   REGEXP_REPLACE (hits_page_pagePath, '-', '') as page_path
   from
   [Intent.All2mon]
   ) X 
   limit 1000
```