# Need to separate the string from a column to multiple columns which is separated by ';' delimeter in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the below scenario 
My column values looked like below :

```
loc=adhesion;pos=31;refresh=559;tag=post;tag=article;tag=business;
```

I want to separate all the values on the basis of ';' delimiter.
Please suggest the code to generate the below result in bigquery.
Example : My output should look like below :
Number of columns should get created with the below values :

```
col1 : loc=adhesion      
Col2 : pos=31     
col3 : refresh=559        
col4 : tag=post
```

and so on
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the SPLIT and NTH functions. See the link below for an example of how to use it.

[BigQuery: SPLIT() returns only one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060396/bigquery-split-returns-only-one-value)